# What is it called when you use the <script> tag to link to link to a php file?

Tags: php, javascript

Our site is linking to php files containing javascript, so the javascript can use php to get data from the database. Here's an example of how these files are linked:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.our-site.com/javascript.php"></script>
```

My question is what is this called? I've tried using google to help me with coding issues, but it's hard when you don't know what to search for.

Comment: It's called a script tag... nothing special about it.

Comment: Google this:  https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=create+javascript+dynamically+by+php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&redir_esc=&ei=wjrgUZ_LCsqJtQaRjIGgDw#safe=off&client=ubuntu&hs=GVi&channel=fs&sclient=psy-ab&q=create+javascript+dynamically+using+php&oq=create+javascript+dynamically+using+php&gs_l=serp.3...6001.7665.0.8055.9.9.0.0.0.0.97.776.9.9.0....0...1c.1.19.psy-ab.O8BbUXCTsk0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.Yms&fp=bbab5b47e5114f19&biw=1280&bih=601

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server-side-generated JavaScript would be an appropriate description. It even shows up on Google autocomplete, and there are [many results](https://www.google.com/search?q=server+side+generated+javascript&oq=server-side+generated+ja&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0j69i60.3764j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=server%20side%20generated%20javascript&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49260673,bs.1,d.cGE&fp=c54e703930fa2c12&biw=1920&bih=1138&pf=p&pdl=300). I am not a fan of this pattern. I find that it is better to keep JavaScript on the view-side completely and just inject the values you need via an `init` method of some sort.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm updating another developer's work and needed to find out how to do what he was doing.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have a special name when it's PHP.

Just make sure you set the header in the PHP file.

```
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
```

Comment: good idea to send no cache and expire headers as well... browsers generally try to aggressively cache js

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is nothing special. It's not named somehow. You just include the PHP file, the PHP file gets interpreted and generates any kind of output which then gets included as regular JavaScript.

If you have issues you might just open up the link to the PHP file and search for your problem there.